Carousel creation and slider
I want to create side a side carousel or slides with WordPress, elementor pro so when I hover on one scales side it scales up and pushes all slides somehow a side; you can check the website of Cristiano Ronaldo, i have attached an image I have already tried the hover in style, but it only scale up the image and i want them somehow linked together
